# perl: why does $hashsize = keys $hash{$foo} give experimental warning, and how can I write it better?

Tags: perl, hash, warnings

I have a hash determined by two factors (I don't know what the correct term for this is), which I generate like so:

```
if (exists $cuthash{$chr}{$bin}){
    $cuthash{$chr}{$bin} += 1;
}else{
    $cuthash{$chr}{$bin} = 1;
}
```

I later want to grab the size of each $chr portion of the hash, which works when I do:

```
for my $chr (sort keys %cuthash){
    my $hashsize = keys $cuthash{$chr};
    ...
}
```

but I get the warning:

```
keys on reference is experimental at ../test.pl line 115.
```

It works, but obviously it's not perfect. What is a better method?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you dereference the hashref

```
my $hashsize = keys %{ $cuthash{$chr} };
```

then there should be no warning.

Comment: @Daniel: It's "better" because `keys` only works on hashes, as you'd expect. The value `$cuthash{$chr}` is a *scalar* that happens to be a hash reference, so historically your syntax would be rejected. Because it's mostly unambiguous to pass a reference here instead of a proper hash, version 14 of Perl 5 introduced an experimental enhancement that allowed you to do that; but being experimental it's liable to change and so shouldn't be used in production code. By the way, try Googling for *Perl nested hash* and look at the [*Perl Data Structures Cookbook*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the explanation. Seems obvious now!

Comment: @Daniel: Most things are when you know :)

Comment: `keys $hash_or_array_ref` is experimental because it's not clear what its behaviour should be in some cases. Using `keys %$hash_ref` or `keys @$array_ref` avoids those cases.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to test for the existence of `$cuthash{$chr}{$bin}` if you use `++` instead of `+= 1` since it doesn't warn when its operand is undef. Just write

```
++$cuthash{$chr}{$bin};
```

instead of the whole of your `if` statement.

In situations like this it can be tidier to extract a local copy of the hash value, either explicitly or using `each`. That way there is no need for a block to delimit the reference expression, so you can write `%$hashref` instead of `%{ $cuthash{$chr} }`. Like so

```
for my $chr (sort keys %cuthash) {
    my $val = $cuthash{$chr};
    my $hashsize = keys %$val;
    ...
}
```

or

```
while ( my ($key, $val) = each %cuthash) {
    my $hashsize = keys %$val;
    ...
}
```

I am sure you can think of a more sensible name for `$val` that reflects its purpose

Comment: That's a handy tip for hash incrementing, been doing it the long way for a while now! The second one makes sense too, and I've used that to make it all tidier. Thanks!